# Can we stop pestering new users?

Tags: discussion

I am a Swift developer, which is a hyped language and most of the questions are from very new users on Stack Overflow.

Almost every first question asked by a new user is bad. It's something we all went through. Swift/iOS has lots of them.

New users just don't understand yet that the voting system is not personal or permanent. They haven't even taken the tour yet. Is it then absolutely necessary to downvote? If such a question gets one downvote is not OK to leave it there? He will not get the first one, 3-4 more won't help anyone.

Even if another user (me) already commented that it is a bad question and linked to the tour, people keep downvoting.

The question that made me start this rant was just above another question that showed no effort from a slightly less new user. He should have gotten a downvote, because he asks bad questions every time. He was referred to the tour, and it was explained to him why his questions were bad and he is unwilling to learn. But he has a rep of 4, so he doesn't get the new user bullying downvotes.

---

So to sum up:

**Why are we downvoting bad questions from new users more than from others and why do we still feel the need to downvote after more information was given?**

Comment: Votes are made on the quality of the question; the relative newness of the asker is irrelevant. Being new and/or ignorant isn't a reason to not get downvoted.

Comment: apparently not.... the questions in question (pun..) were equally horrible

Comment: @EdCottrell it is a duplicate of a whole lot of questions ;)

Comment: Correlation does not imply causation.

Comment: Nobody's "pestering" anyone. The down votes have a valuable signaling function; they are big part of why this site has so much valuable information. The bad stuff gets weeded out. And since each user only gets one vote, really bad questions that show no effort *should* get multiple down votes.

Comment: @MartinJames true, but it happens a lot, it was just so striking now because the questions were above/below one another

Comment: @RMenke Too true. I just went with the first one I liked. :)

Comment: @EdCottrell I am also not questioning the usefulness of downvotes on bad questions no matter who posted them. They should get downvotes and disappear as quickly as possible. I just don't get downvoting a new user without taking the time to also help them out. Not with their bad question, but with adjusting to SO.

Comment: @RMenke up and down votes aren't primarily for the post's author; they're for everyone else, to signal the value of the post. We don't vote up or down users. We vote up or down questions. And commenting when (or instead of) down voting is a topic that comes up on here almost every day. For the most part, it's unnecessary. If a question is about to be closed as too broad, for example, there will be a helpful message there automatically when it's closed. It's not always necessary to post *another* message explaining the problem.

Comment: `New users just don't understand yet that the voting system is not personal or permanent.` -- BZZZTT!

Comment: `Almost every first question asked by a new user is bad.` -- BZZZTT!

Comment: (That is the sound of the buzzer on Family Feud.)

Comment: @EdCottrell good point. Didn't think about it like that yet. I considered it mostly as an incentive for the user to improve/remove the question. In that case one downvote is not enough as it is one mans opinion. 3-4 downvotes send a clear message, not to waste time.

Comment: I'm sorry, but a ' user that takes time to comment on questions of new users and even edit them to improve them' has no life.  They are condemned to an existence of drudgery and servitude to the vast majority of vampire deadbeats who have no intention of following up on any advice given.

Comment: @MartinJames: Editing was always about making a good question better, not about heroically rescuing a bad post.

Comment: [new users don't value reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269120/new-users-dont-value-reputation)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why are we donwnvoting bad questions from new users more than from others and why do we still feel the need to downvote after more info was given?

- Well, we are certainly downvoting more bad questions from new users, as most questions are from low-rep users.
- We are certainly also downvoting fewer questions (proportionally) from established users, as users which are a complete waste of space don't tend to get that many upvotes.
- Also, there's the first-post-queue, which tends to result in one additional vote (too often instead of a good edit and/or comment), though normally positive even if the post is mediocre.
- Why should the fact that the user got some advice mean the post should not be judged as-is, thus marking it appropriately for other viewers after already having gone to the effort of reading it? Did it cease to exist, and thus stop wasting peoples time?
- If the post is still bad, why shouldn't it result in still more downvotes? Anecdotally, there are also users which just follow the herd, but are you *sure* that's the case there?